# Different font size in restructuredtext

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have bigger fonts on all type of lists.

What should I do to keep the same font size in lists as in my normal paragraphs?

For now I get this

```
Plain text  Typical result (in normal font size)

Bullet lists (in normal font size):

- This is item 1 (in bigger font size)
- This is item 2 (in bigger font size)
```

Comment: What tool do you use to generate output?

Comment: @mzjn I use sphinx

Comment: Can you link to your project or provide a small example project?
And what is/are your output format(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Sphinx generates depends on the theme you use. The theme *sphinxdoc* generates the same font size in bullet lists and in normal text. Spinx defines the theme in *conf.py* in the base folder of the documentation. Search there for "html_theme".

More information about themes and Sphinx [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/theming.html)