# Paragraph tag not rendering in RestructuredText table cell

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I define the following table in restructuredtext:

```
+-------------------------+--------------------+
| Label                   |Description         |
+=========================+====================+
| foo                     |Two options:        |
|                         |                    |
|                         |* Thing 1           |
|                         |* Thing 2           |
+-------------------------+--------------------+
| bar                     |Bar does something. |
+-------------------------+--------------------+
```

When this gets rendered in html (using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/)), the "*Two options:*" text gets wrapped in a paragraph tag. The "*Bar does something.*" text does not get rendered with a paragraph tag. When the stylesheets are applied, this results in the cell text looking different:

[image]

Is there a way to force the same behavior for both cases?

Comment: "Two options:" is a paragraph and "Bar does something" is a table cell. But what is wrong with the output? What do you mean by "same behaviour"?

Comment: The problem is "Two options:" and "Bar does something" render differently because one has a paragraph tag around it and the other does not. You can see in the attached image, the one without the paragraph tag is smaller. This makes the tables render funny, so that multiline cells have larger text than single line cells. If there was a way to force the single line cells to render as paragraphs, it would resolve the issue for me.

Comment: What Sphinx theme do you use? Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39285425/407651.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using a custom theme based on alabaster.

Comment: OK, then I guess that you may need to add or update some CSS rule(s) in that theme.

Comment: Is it a CSS issue? The html being generated is actually different, so I currently need different rules to get the same content. If the html was not different, then I could apply the same CSS rule and get consistent results.

Comment: What happens if you use the stock alabaster theme without any customizations?

Comment: I switched to alabaster and then basic and classic and they all generate the same html as my custom theme.

Comment: Too bad no one has an answer for this. Everyone seems to misunderstand the question. Frustrating! This might have changed in newer Sphinx version, I get `<p>` that wraps single line text inside table cells.

Comment: @Moberg if you are getting the paragraph tag now for single line text, it sounds like the issue has been resolved with the newer version of Sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx' way to change CSS declarations: add in your conf.py a line

```
templates_path = ['my_template_path']
```

and add in *my_template_path* a file layout.html. There you can override the css classes of your theme which define the layout of the table contents. The class names depend on your theme. Try to find it out with the developers features of you browser. In my theme the definition of the first paragraph is *class="first"*. Here I overwrite it with

```
td > p.first { margin: 0; }
```

The list ul has *class="last simple"*, overwritten by

```
td > ul.last.simple { margin: 0; }
```

The *layout.html* should have the form

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
<style type="text/css">

/* Add class definitions here */

</style>
```

Hope that helps. Some more explanations [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html) and in [this stackoverflow-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622698/customize-sphinxdoc-theme).